# How to send data in a java socket program without closing socket

Tags: java, sockets, streaming, apache-spark, serversocket

i created a sever socket program to send a stream data to Apache spark.But data is received by spark after i close the socket or termination of program.i need to send data without closing socket and terminating program.

```
 import java.io.DataOutputStream;
 import java.net.ServerSocket;
 import java.net.Socket;
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class SocketServer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(9999);
        Socket s = ss.accept();// establishes connection

        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1 = "";
        while (!s1.equals("end")) {
            s1 = scanner.next();
            dout.writeUTF(s1);
            dout.flush();
        }
     ss.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {r
        System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

i can send data in stream using nc server **nc -lk 9999**.

**EDIT -1 Tried with println**

```
try {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(6000);
        Socket s = ss.accept();// establishes connection

        OutputStream ostream = s.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter pwrite = new PrintWriter(ostream, true);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1 = "";
        while (!s1.equals("end")) {
            s1 = scanner.next();
            pwrite.println(s1);
            pwrite.flush();
        }
        ss.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Still not working.

Please help..

Comment: why do you instantiate `dout` in every iteration of the loop?

Comment: Sorry wrong snippet..

Comment: Though i flush.. still data is not received by spark stream receiver..

Comment: how is `write` a `println` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless Apache Spark is (a) written in Java and (b) calling `readUTF()` you're using the wrong method to send. You should probably be using a `println()` method. You also need to close the accepted socket, as well as the server socket.

Comment: Your text says you tried with `println(),` but your code shows that you didn't. Try again.

Comment: Awesome man..Works like charm.Verify my edit code in question.

Answer (score -2):

First of all you should only be instantiating dout once (before the start of the while loop).

Secondly I believe the way it works is that when reading from a socket stream it reads until the end of the stream is reached (ie socket is closed). To finish reading early you'd need to send an "end of stream" without closing it.

Comment: How to send an "end of stream"??

Comment: @BlackPOP Shutdown the socket for output. But you will never be able to send on it again.

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure the only way to send the end of stream message is to close the socket sorry.

Comment: @KageOni No it isn't. I've already provided another way, see above.

Comment: @EJP Ahh I see ty :) Essentially the same thing in this case though right? As he can no longer continue using it so send again.

Comment: No it isn't. You can keep reading after you shutdown the socket for output.